# Change CSS of div when ATBar button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, dom

Currently trying to fix an issue with a WordPress site. The site has the ATBar plugin installed which is an accessibility plugin with a toolbar at the top of every page. This toolbar overlaps the normal Wordpress Toolbar and therefore I have added some CSS to the WP toolbar to push it down a bit:

```
 top: 40px;
```

As 40px is the height of the ATBar. Unfortunately when the ATBar is closed (via a button on the toolbar) the gap is left at the top.

I've tried binding a click event to the ATBar close button but it has no effect, possibly because the ATBar is dynamically loaded with JS on page load. Therefore, I've tried only binding the event when the window is ready, as opposed to the document, but no effect either!

The site is here: http://simp.daveclarke.me/, you will see the two bars if you visit this page.

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried binding a click event to the ATBar close button but it has no effect, possibly because the ATBar is dynamically loaded with JS on pag

I think it's not a problem with loading the JS dynamically but the fact that the wordpress bar has an !important in the CSS top attribute. If you can remove the !important tag and then do something like:

```
document.getElementById('at-lnk-atkit-unload').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('wpadminbar').style.top = "1px"
});
```

That should fix the issue

Comment: Definitely a good idea, but unfortunately that gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null` - presumably because the obj doesn't exist when it's run.

Comment: ok, so the ATBar is loaded later than your code, right? You can add that into a callback to be executed right after the bar is loaded. I'm not familiar with that ATBar but it's a common pattern that this kind of components allow to pass callbacks after instantiation.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much documentation available and I can't see anything obvious. I'l continue to investigate, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like

```
$('#at-lnk-atkit-unload').click(function(){ //when ATbar close btn is clicked
   $('#wpadminbar').css({ "top": "0"});
});
```

Comment: My first thought too, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I think this is caused by the fact that the ATBar is dynamically loaded & added to the page. Not too sure though...

Comment: Try adding it to the plugin JS if you have acces to it

Comment: It's loaded from their site unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$('#at-lnk-atkit-unload').on('click', function(){` ...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question..

Managed to fix this in the end, by tweaking their JS a little.

Rather than importing the JS source from their server, I made a copy at my end and added the addEventListener call that @emilioicai suggested just after the ATBar was rendered. This adds the event listener and functionality required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, that problem lies in that: ATBar loaded after your code, so event listeners didn't attach.

And if you don't want to copy foreign code to your server (which is not appropriate decision, 'cause it will not work all the time, API of ATBar may evolve and so on), you may use timeouts

```
setTimeout(yourfunc,0); //if loading takes a lot of time, then
// change 0 to 50 or whatever
```

Or just use jQuery .on function (or even deprecated .live function)